# R Programming : Error in Printing dataTableOutput

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to send an input from Shiny UI SelectInput to server script and my server.R will read specific columns from a table and compute min, max, mean, median data. I am able to execute this and got right data when executed line by line in R Console. Not able to send this as an Shiny output and print as a table in Shiny UI browser. Server.R script should take input from UI and execute mean, median for that specific input only. Appreciate your valuable help.

```
# ui.R
library(shiny)
library(RODBC)
library(DBI)
dbconnect <- odbcConnect("orecloud", uid="XXXX", pwd="XXXX", believeNRows=FALSE)
df <- data.frame()
df <- sqlQuery(dbconnect,"SELECT distinct cpan FROM CYTOKINE ")
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  headerPanel("ORE Cytokine Summary"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Please select Patient Details.."),
      selectInput("CPAN", 
                  label = "Choose patient",
                  choices = df,
                  selected = NULL),
    submitButton(text = "Submit", icon = NULL)),
    mainPanel(
         dataTableOutput("tableoutput")
    )
  )
 ))

# server.R
library(RODBC)
library(RODBC)
library(lattice)
shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {
    dbconnect <- odbcConnect("orecloud", uid="XXXX", pwd="XXXX", believeNRows=FALSE)
    df2 = reactive({
      # Created DB Connection to get details 
      input_var <- input$CPAN
      my_query <- paste("select CPAN,SCTP,MARKER,RESULT from TABLE where CPAN= ", input_var)
      sqlQuery(dbconnect,my_query)

      cleandata <- na.omit(data)
      colnames(cleandata)
      Markers <- unique(cleandata[,"MARKER"])
      #Markers
      nMarkers <- length(Markers)
      nMarkers
      Patients <- unique(cleandata[,"CPAN"])
      nPatients <- length(Patients)
      nPatients
      #Output columns defined
      output <- data.frame("Marker","Patient", "Min","Q1","Median","Mean","Q3","Max",stringsAsFactors=FALSE,check.names=FALSE)
       for (i in 1:nMarkers) {
        Mrk <- Markers[i]    
        for (j in 1:nPatients){
          Pnt <- Patients[j]
          Mrkdata  <- cleandata[which(cleandata[,'MARKER']== Mrk),]
          Ptntdata <- Mrkdata[which(Mrkdata[,'CPAN']==Pnt), ]
          output[{i-1}*nPatients+j,1] <- Mrk
          output[{i-1}*nPatients+j,2] <- Pnt
          for (k in 1:6){
            output[{i-1}*nPatients+j,k+2] <- summary(Ptntdata[,'RESULT'])[k]
            #histogram(~Mrkdata [,'RESULT'])
          }
          #output[j,9]<- quantile(Mrkdata[,'RESULT'],c(.25,.75))[1]
          #output[j,10]<- quantile(Mrkdata[,'RESULT'],c(.25,.75))[2]
        }        
      } 
    })
    output$tableoutput <- renderDataTable({df2()}) 
       } )
```

Comment: Your df2 doesn't return anything

Comment: When i am trying to render output it is throwing error like unknown variable: